# Open multiple pdf files with python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pdf

I want to open multiple pdf files from a specific directory.The name of these files are taken from a csv file and it opened each matching between the csv and the name of the pdf file.

My problem is that only first match is opened not all.How can I fix that?

The code that I tried:

```
import csv
import os
from pathlib import *

file1=open('CSV file.csv','r')
reader=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
file_name=[]

dir_path = Path('C:\\path\\of\\directory')
pdf_files = dir_path.glob('*.pdf')

for item in reader:
    file_name=item[1]
    print(file_name)#just to see the file name that I want to open
    for pdffile in pdf_files:
        if item[1] in pdffile.name:
            os.startfile("%s"%(pdffile))

file1.close()
```

Comment: When you say you want to open PDF files, what do you mean? Do you want to somehow extract information from them, or perhaps launch them in a PDF viewer?

Comment: Second option..thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring potential filename lettercase issues, the reason only one pdf file is being opened is because `dir_path.glob('*.pdf')` returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) object which you attempt to iterate over multiple times using the nested `for pdffile in pdf_files:` loop.

The simplest way to fix that is to convert the generator into a sequence object, like a `list`, that can be iterated over multiple times. I've done this in the code below as well as corrected or simplified a couple of other things.

```
import csv
import os
from pathlib import *

dir_path = Path('C:\\path\\of\\directory')
pdf_files = list(dir_path.glob('*.pdf'))  # convert result to a list

with open('CSV file.csv', newline='') as file1:
    for row in csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';'):
        file_name = row[1]
        print(file_name)
        for pdffile in pdf_files:
            if file_name in pdffile.name:
                os.startfile(str(pdffile))
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to iterate over the file names in your csv file and check every time if the file exists, instead of creating another list with existing files in the directory. You could use `os.path.isfile()` for that check.

Here's an example:

```
import csv
import os

# access list with file names
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    reader=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')

# iterate over files and open them
for item in reader:
    if os.path.isfile(item):
        print item
        os.startfile(item)
```

By using the `with open()` formalism, you don't have to bother closing the file afterwards.

Comment: In this case, the path of csv should be the same with path of pdf files directory ?

Comment: To be more specific...the csv file provide a code and I want to open from a specific directory the pdf file that match or contains in the file name respective code

Comment: if `item` is absolute (something like 'C://path/file1.pdf'), you can use the code in my answer.

However if the file name `item` is relative (like _file1.pdf_), the files have to be in the current working directory. Otherwise you can easily connect a "path-string" to your filename-string:
`fullpath = path + filename`

Comment: "item" from reader object is not like 'C://path/file1.pdf' , it is like 'file1' and I want to open from a specific directory the pdf file('C://path/file1.pdf') with name "file1" like I open it with double-click mouse ,but the issue is that  my code that I tried open only first match. How can I open the other pdf files from that directory that also were matched with the item from reader?

Comment: Not sure if I understood. are there several files in a folder that match _file1_?

Comment: My csv file provide something like 'file1', 'file2' and so on...and I want to open from a specific directory the pdf file named 'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf' and all pdf file that matches with items provided from csv file

Comment: ok. So, does every item '_fileX_' we read from the csv file correspond to exactly **one** pdf file you want to open?
If so, you can: 
1. build a full path from every item with `fullpath = path + item + '.pdf'`,
2. check if the file exists with `os.path.isfile(fullpath)`, 
3. open it with `os.startfile()` or, like Martin suggested, with `subprocess.Popen()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want. First it reads in the second column entries from the CSV file and creates a lowercased set holding all of the filenames to be searched for. Next it uses the `glob.glob()` function to get a list of PDF files from your chosen folder. Lastly it checks to see if the file is in the list of required `pdf_filenames`, and if it is, launches them using the shell.

```
import subprocess    
import glob    
import csv
import os

folder = r'C:\path\of\directory\*.pdf'

# Read the list of PDF filenames from the CSV
with open('CSV file.csv','r') as f_pdf_list:
    pdf_filenames = set(row[1].lower() for row in csv.reader(f_pdf_list, delimiter=';'))

# Get the list of files in the folder    
for pdf_file in glob.glob(folder):
    pdf_file = os.path.basename(pdf_file).lower()

    if pdf_file in pdf_filenames:
        subprocess.Popen([pdf_file], shell=True)
```

Note, I lowercase all of the filenames as Windows is case insensitive.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it seems that no pdf file is open....neither the one that I managed to open it with my code

Comment: I'm guessing your csv file only contains the name and not the path. I've modified the script.

Comment: Exactly...my csv contains only the names of pdf files